# How to get Image type, file size and url?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, image-upload, name

is it possible to get Image filename and path, type (jpg,png etc) and file size(in bytes)?

In fact I need the same data that you get from an image upload form, but I need to retrieve them from already saved images using magento uploader.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is useful for you

```
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader(
        array(
    'name' => $_FILES['images']['name'][$key],
    'type' => $_FILES['images']['type'][$key],
    'tmp_name' => $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key],
    'error' => $_FILES['images']['error'][$key],
    'size' => $_FILES['images']['size'][$key]
        )
);
```

Comment: in fact I need to get those exact fields for a file already store using uploader